# While Loop in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I'm struggling to figure out the correct syntax to use in MYSQL.

```
label1: WHILE income <= 3000 DO
SET income = income + starting_value;
END WHILE label1;
```

I keep getting an error saying it's incorrect syntax. Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What did you want to do? provide some sample data and expect result that really help

Comment: `WHILE` and `END WHILE` and `labels` can **only** be used in stored programs like functions, procedures and triggers.

Comment: Looking to this "SQL code" i geuss you need `UPDATE table SET income = income + starting_value WHERE income <= 3000` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a while loop for this logic in any language.  You can do:

```
set income = (ceil((3000 - income) / startingvalue) * startingvalue + income);
```